# Can't save large files with Postgres, JDBCTemplate, Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

In our company we use Spring Core (4.0.4), JDBCTemplate and Postgres 9.3.

When I try [this example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-parameter-handling):

I have some problems with large files (> 200MB).
I adapted the example for my scenario:

```
public void addToDB(final long documentId, final File file) throws IOException {
    String sql = "insert into filetest (id, content) values (?,?)";
    final InputStream blobIs = new FileInputStream(file);
    DefaultLobHandler defaultLobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
    jdbcTemplate
            .execute(sql, new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(defaultLobHandler) {

                @Override
                protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setLong(1, documentId);
                    lobCreator
                            .setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, 2, blobIs, (int) file
                                    .length());
                }
            });
    blobIs.close();
}
```

on Postgres I created the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE filetest
 (
      id bigint,
      content bytea
 )
 WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
  );
 ALTER TABLE filetest
 OWNER TO postgres;
 ALTER TABLE filetest ALTER COLUMN content SET STORAGE EXTERNAL;
```

And I have my test that call the repository with the above method.
For small files the code works (with pgAdmin client, I can connect and I see the two records).

When I try to load large files (more than 200 MB ) I can save the file (the implementation did not give me errors). However, when I try to read in from the pgAdmin, then it aborts the operation. Only when I select the id record, I don't have problems to see it (only the content record abort the search). I think this can occurs why the record is corrupted (how can I check this?) or why the GUI-Client can't load the record (I tried it from console, and also there I have strange behavior)

Now the question are:

- Is there any parameter of Postgres that can limit the size? (bytea can handle 1GB)
- Is there any check that I can make that the data are written to DB?

Because when I try to read (programmatically) from the record I get a Java Heap Space exception.

Comment: Any error you get ???

Comment: Compare size of file and DB filed size ? You have to read that field and calculate it's size.

Comment: Limiting the size of the returned result isn't the responsibility of Postgres (the server), the client needs to limit the size. If you are asking if you can ensure that you don't store more than x bytes in a `bytea` column then use a check constraint

Comment: I wouldn't recommend storing over a couple of hundred MB in a `bytea` field anyway. The whole thing needs to fit in RAM a couple of times over, it's not very efficient at all. The limit is 1GB so you're already getting uncomfortably close to it at design time. Consider `pg_largeobject` or using the filesystem.

Comment: At the end the solution was to go on pg_largeobject (txs Craig Ringer) . user3145373: no error message are shown (only the java heap space Exception)

Answer (score 0):

*Because when I try to read (programmatically) from the record I get a Java Heap Space exception.*

Possible solution is to set `-Xmx2048m` and `-Xms256m` `JVM` parameters to increase the Heap size. like:

```
java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m REST_OF_ARGUMENTS
```

The flag can also be specified in multiple sizes, such as KB, MB, and so on.

```
-Xmx2048k
-Xmx1024m
-Xmx2g
```

Comment: Tank you: this had no effect on the error. (But now the problem was solved otherwise)